# Multi-select dropdown on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59843941/google-sheets-scripts-relating-to-multiple-columns) explaining how to create multi-select dropdowns in Google Sheets. I modified it slightly (my dropdown values need to apply in column B, rows 2-23) and ended up here:

```
function onEdit(e){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("User outreach");

var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();

if(activeCell.getColumn() == 2 && activeCell.getRow() < 23){

  activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

  var headers = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, 2).getValues();

  var headersIndex = headers[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;

  if(headersIndex != 0){

    var validationRange = datass.getRange(2, headersIndex, datass.getLastRow());
    var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);

    }

  }



}
```

I have very little experience using scripts in Google Sheets, but nothing seems to be happening. Do I need to do anything besides save the script in order to use it? Or is there a problem in the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that in your situation, it is required to check your Spreadsheet for replicating your issue of `but nothing seems to be happening`. Because I think that when your Spreadsheet is not correct for your script, the if statement is always `false`. I'm worried about this. I apologize for this.

Comment: It might help to share a copy of your spreadsheet.  To answer your first question (Do I need to do anything besides save the script?), in this case, no, because "onEdit" is a special function name (a "simple trigger") that will run automatically each time the spreadsheet is edited.

Comment: I looked at your spreadsheet and I cannot determine from it how you wish you drops downs to appear or operate can you provide more information?

Comment: @MiMi thanks! Basically I'd like to be able to select multiple options in the same cell (for example, not just having to choose between "A" or "B", but be able to have "A" and "B" appear in the same cell)

Comment: Edit: deleted comment with link to spreadsheet

Comment: OK, you want to create a dropdown. Completely understand that. And you want to create it "onEdit", so, when the cell has already been edited. So the dropdown would never open and never be visible, right?